# phpmyadmin how can i create a event like this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating an event on one of my databases to check if the client changed a specific parameter called '**serverlog**' which is a boolean on my Sql database.

Is there a way to loop through all the users in a table called '**users**', check if 's**erverlog**' is false and update/set a different parameter called '**islogged**' in the user table.
Something like a foreach user loop in **SQL**

I want to loop through all the users and if '**serverlog**' = false then set '**islogged**' = false on that user.

Comment: Queries works with data arrays (tables) and does not need in any "loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to loop through all the users and if 'serverlog' = false then set 'islogged' = false on that user.

```sql
UPDATE users_table
SET islogged = FALSE
WHERE NOT serverlog;
```